# Check if DataGrid ItemSource is populated via binding or assignment

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datagrid

Is there a way to find out (in code) if the ItemSource of the Datagrid was set via binding, or if there was an assignment?

Binding:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="MyGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding Foo}"/>
```

Assignment:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="MyGrid" />
```

```
MyGrid.ItemsSource = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is a framework method to detect a Binding: [BindingOperations.GetBindingExpression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.bindingoperations.getbindingexpression)

> Returns the BindingExpression object associated with the given property or null if none exists

```
var binding = BindingOperations.GetBindingExpression(MyGrid, DataGrid.ItemsSourceProperty);
string result = (binding == null) ? "assignment" : "binding";
```

Answer (score 0):

[[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/waMYs.png][1]

The image shows how you can conclude that the grid is getting populated with the required values. Also MyGird.Items.Results View value in debugger displays the actual values. In your case Foo variable should be a list of int. The correct way of binding Foo is given below.

In code behind:

```
public List<int> Foo { get; set; }

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Foo = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3 };
            MyGrid.ItemsSource = Foo;
        }
```

In XAML

```
<Grid>
        <DataGrid x:Name="MyGrid">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding}"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
```